# Play framework mongodb seed

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I would like to seed some data on creation of a new database. Where do I place these scripts or how do I go about it?

`Global.onStart`?

Comment: This would usually be part of the installation procedure of your application.

Comment: I see, so no facility like seed.rb like ror???